# Management requests on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, mobile-device-management, mdm

I have a MacBook Pro and all the time, I keep receiving this message about enrollment.(For anyone wondering if it’s stolen, I don’t think so because it belonged to my friends grandmother who had worked for the district trying to enroll it. She had given the device to him, who subsequently gave it to me.) Every time I receive it, I just hit details and hit cancel. How do I stop the pop-up that appears?

[image]

> Device Enrollment
>
> School District can automatically configure your Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The school district needs to remove it from their Mobile Device Management server. It may not be stolen but it wasn’t returned.

When employers or schools buy Macs they do so with an identifying code registered with Apple. The device will phone home to Apple who redirects to the registered MDM server where it will auto enroll and receive MDM configuration in a zero touch manner. Even if you wipe it completely.

You should call the school district IT and give them the serial number.  It belongs to the school district until they relinquish it from the MDM server.

It is not normal operating procedure to just let someone keep a Mac. They usually donate to charity instead. It’s a liability issue and a tax write off.